# Custom Panes Scripts Syspro

Tags: listview, vbscript

How do I resolve an issue with two custom panes using the same vb.script. One of the panes is a .NET User Control the other is a ListView that should use the vb.script I updated.

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks in advance

DanielR

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that one of the two panes should not be using the vbscript file? In that case, you can delete the .NET User Control's pane and re-create it. When setting up the customized pane, you should have the option to define its own vbscript file.

If any of the fields in any forms were linked to the .NET User Control's pane, you'll want to make sure they are still linked after recreating the pane. You can see what is currently linked by right-clicking any field in a form -> Options -> Highlight Fields Linked to User Control.

Alternatively, you can back-up the ListView's vbscript and recreate that pane instead. I hope this helps.